# Squid server issues after upgrade (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, ubuntu-14.04

We have upgraded a squid proxy server from a previous version of Ubuntu (Can't recall what it was sorry) to version 14.04.2.  Now it appears Squid will not start / VM's can not reach internet through proxy.  I noticed there maybe an issue with services when moving from CLI to Webmin and i saw i could "Start Service"  I clicked this and got the error

```
Failed to start Squid :
squid3 start/running, process 12431
```

Moved back to the CLI and ran `sudo service squid start` and got the following:

```
squid3 start/running, process 12637
```

So ... Is it running?  Why is webmin showing to start the service...

Saw some forums online to restart the service tis didn't help.  `Running service squid3 status` shows:

```
MGT-VM-PRX:/var/log/squid3$ service squid3 status
squid3 stop/waiting
```

Has anyone noticed this or know what has changed by upgrade?

I can also see that there are two services under a ps -aux | grep squid and squid3

Have just checked logs /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1 and the issues seems to the service not starting / working as logs stopped on the 19th when issues are being discovered.

---

UPDATE

---

Fixed by removing the line : acl manager proto cache_object

from

```
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
```

Run the following:

```
azzurri@MGT-VM-PRX:~$ squid3 -k parse
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initializing Authentication Schemes ...
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'basic'
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'digest'
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'negotiate'
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'ntlm'
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Startup: Initialized Authentication.
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Processing Configuration File: /etc/squid3/squid.conf (depth 0)
2015/06/22 12:38:08| Processing: acl manager proto cache_object
2015/06/22 12:38:08| aclParseAclLine: ACL 'manager' already exists with different type.
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid3/squid.conf line 694: acl manager proto cache_object
Squid Cache (Version 3.3.8): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.007 seconds = 0.003 user + 0.003 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 20496 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

All seem's ok for now, but i'm not sure what this does?  Can anyone clarify if this is a suitable fix?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run syntax check `squid3 -k check`? If you know the previous version, taking a look at change log might help or the current config review with  http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/, there may be directives which might have been depreciated in the version - squid upgraded to.

Comment: as per the doc the recommended config section directives are all build in (3.3) so no need to mention them. Remove was the fix, you already done.